# In a critical section problem, why are the processes deciding which process should go next? Isn't this the job of a scheduling algorithm?

Tags: operating-system, critical-section

The context is Operating Systems - Critical Section problem.
One of the three protocols to solve the critical section problem is **Progress**:

Progress is : If no process is executing in its critical section and some processes wish to enter their critical sections, then only **those processes** that are not executing in their remainder section **can participate** in deciding which will enter its critical section next, and this selection cannot be postponed indefinitely.

Why are the processes deciding which process should go next? Isn't this the job of a scheduling algorithm?

Comment: Well, though the text is not clear, only processes have threads, only threads have execution and only execution can run a scheduling algorithm.